# Capture text from current document

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-word, c#-3.0

How can i do to capture the text you are writing in a word document, using c # and save it to memory.
Sorry for my english and thanks for yours answers

Comment: Red up on office automation, it allows you to interact with Microsoft Word

Comment: Please post some code you've tried and errors you're getting. See the posting guidelines for Stack Overflow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to add `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to References from here.

[image]

Then you can read the sentences in your Word document to string list like this:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

public List<string> ReadWordDoc()
{
    object objMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;            
    //Start Word application.
    Word._Application wordApp;
    Word._Document wordDoc;
    wordApp = new Word.Application();
    wordApp.Visible = false;

    object fileName = @"c:\temp\TestWord.docx";

    wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
        ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
        ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
        ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing);

    List<string> sentences = new List<string>();    // List to store sentences.
    Word.Range rng;
    for (int i = 1; i < wordDoc.Sentences.Count+1; i++)
    {
        object startLocation = wordDoc.Sentences[i].Start;
        object endLocation = wordDoc.Sentences[i].End;

        // Supply a Start and End value for the Range. 
        rng = wordDoc.Range(ref startLocation, ref endLocation);

        // Select the Range.
        rng.Select();
        sentences.Add(rng.Text);
    }
    object doNotSaveChanges = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
    wordDoc.Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref objMissing, ref objMissing);
    wordApp.Quit(ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing);

    return sentences;
}
```

Comment: Thank my friends, all OK, but the problem is that I need to capture text from a word in use.
I try to do this from a Word addin. Thanks a lot

Comment: I resolved that, using two save method, while i the user write in one the other read

Answer (score 1):

@Batista: If you're asking how you can monitor what the user is doing in the Word application - "capture the text you are writing" - then the short answer is that you cannot. There is nothing in the Word APIs that supports monitoring keystrokes and mouse actions, short of a few events such as WindowSelectionChange, WindowBeforeDoubleClick and WindowBeforeRightClick.

The longer answer is that some monitoring is possible using the Windows API. If you do a Google search you should turn up a number of discussions with some code samples. The ones I've seen are in the VSTO forum on MSDN (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=vsto). Your mileage may vary, however, as the effectiveness of the Windows API to intercept messages in the Word application differs between versions of Word and of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jhmt, Your solution was very helpful. but This the **loop** between the sentences take much time in largest documents.

Here its my solution now:

```
var objRange = Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveDocument.Range();
```

then with `objRange.Text` already have all text the document.